# Cross-Browser solution for downloading canvas-content?

Tags: html, cross-browser, download

I'm looking for a solution to download the content of a canvas-element. The background: we have a clientside QR-Code-generator and up to now it is only possible to print this codes. Our customers wish to be able to save this codes, e.g. to attach them to their sales slip. Until now i only have a working solution for Google Chrome using an anchor-tag:

HTML Code:

```
<a href="data:image/octet-stream;base64,{base64-string}" class="btn" data-mimetype="image/jpeg" download="Kunden-Zufriedenheitsumfrage.jpeg">JPEG</a>
```

The problem is that Firefox ignores the 'download'-attribute and sets a wrong filename (first x letters of the base64-string + extension .part) and the Internet Explorer doesn't even know what to do (nothing happens).

Sure, it would be possible to give our customers the image-tag, so they could rightclick it and save the image over the context menu, but this isn't very intuitive.

Here is a screenshot of the QR-Code-window:
[image]

Comment: As far as I know webkit is still the only browser which supports the download attribute, although firefox is up to it: http://javascript-reverse.tumblr.com/post/37056936789/html5-download-attribute

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm glad to see, that the reported "bug" is now in status "RESOLVED FIXED". I just hope, that Microsoft will follow Mozilla and Google and implement support for it soon. :(

Comment: I'm having this same issue in firefox and it's almost 2015.